# active_recrod_delayed_job is being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, delayed-job, rails-activejob

i have used `active_record_delayed_job' before without problem.

i added to Gemfile

`gem 'delayed_job_active_record'` 
`rails g delayed_job:active_record`
`rake db:migrate`

`$ rake jobs:work`

> Starting job worker

```
class CreateTopicJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(object)
    #stuff here
  end
end

photo.rb

after_save :create_topics 

def create_topics
  CreateTopicJob.perform_later(self)
end
```

all of the topics get created, but nothing is happening inside of

`$ rake jobs:work`

> Starting job worker

and even if i close that terminal all the topics are still created.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking *why is it working? I don't think this is supposed to be working, but it is*?

Comment: ...In which case, presumably because you're running a background `delayed_job` task. Have a look: `ps aux | grep delayed_job`